# Error when using Database Helper

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm using Database Helper and I got an error saying

> SQLiteException near "/" syntax error;

My `DB_PATH` is

```
/data/data/com.mypackage/databases/
```

My `DB_NAME is`loading`. I can't see what is causing the error.

Comment: fuul log cat and class in which exception came.........

Comment: once give double hash symbols & execute. like.. "//data//data//com.mypackage//databases//". single hash("/") means it considers as escape sequence character...

Comment: No way you don't need to do this, thats ridiculous, that only will be executed like that if you are printing not creating the path for database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you should do something like this :

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.mypackage/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "DBNAME.db";

String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
```

then use the path like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

But remember to make sure you add ".db" at the end of your database name, and the actual database has .db, it is an obvious practice but sometimes is the main issue :)

Good Luck

Comment: but first I got this error when I first run the app                          06-27 18:29:51.283: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(3304): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.frux.kfcmobile/databases/data", &handle, 1, NULL) failed                                                after I run the app again its say the error                                 06-27 18:32:11.692: E/AndroidRuntime(4378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.frux.kfcmobile/com.frux.kfcmobile.KFCmobileActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error